# htaccess RewriteCond for RewriteRule everything except of

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to set up the following scenario:

I need to get URLs like **/Login or /Start** to be redirected to `core.php?fn=Login or core.php?fn=Start`

But whenever I enter smth like `/profile_id` I want it to be redirected to `profile.php?profile_id=profile_id`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core.php?fn=$1`
Bit it throws out an 500 error.

How can i set up that one?

Comment: Please add some code, and content of your .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(Login|Start)/?$ core.php?fn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?profile_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only works partially. The second RewriteRule kills stuff like /api/showMyPicture

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.